# JSONP quebra nos dois pontos (" : ")

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, restful

O server envia um JSON, normal. Segue o código:

```
@GET
@Path("email")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getEmail(){
    ViewStatisticsEmail statisticsEmail = new ViewStatisticsEmail();
    statisticsEmail.setDoacoes(1432);
    statisticsEmail.setLidas(5443);
    statisticsEmail.setNaoLidas(4667);
    statisticsEmail.setSent(10000);
    statisticsEmail.setVisualization("Atualizado por ultimo " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return new Gson().toJson(statisticsEmail);
}
```

E estou usando ajax para desenhar um gráfico com essas informações. Segue o código do ajax:

```js
function chartEmail() {
    var url = 'http://192.168.0.42:8080/Admin/service/email';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Task', 'valores'],
                ['Lidas',     data.lidas],
                ['Não lidas',      data.naoLidas],
                ['Doações',  data.doacoes]
            ]);

            var options = {
                title : data.sent,
                legend : "bottom",
                pieHole: 0.4
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart-email'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });
  }
```

É o google charts.

Aí vem pra mim o seguinte erro: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token`:

[image: E o JSON quebra assim]

Comment: Porquê `jsonp`? isso parece um JSON normal... (sem padding)

Comment: Então... esse é o problema, se eu ponho json normal ele dá "no Access control allow origin

Comment: Isso é porque o servidor não permite ligações externas. O servidor e essa página estão são mesmo dominio?

Comment: Sergio é localhost os dois... mais ainda e testes, quando for pra produção não vai ser mais... como faço pro servidor habilitar ligações externas?

Comment: Se você mudar de *jsonp* para *json*, [essa resposta aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23631475/540552) te ajuda?

Comment: deu outro erro victor GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Jersey REST Service] in context with path [/Admin] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause

Comment: Em Java não posso ajudar muito, mas podes dar uma olhada aqui: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-add-cors-support-on-the-server-side-in-java-with-jersey/ e certamente virá alguém que ajude nisso. Entretanto em desenvolvimento usa os endereços sem `http://192.168.0.42:8080`, ou seja relativos. Isso faz com que o browser perceba que o ajax é local e já não bloqueia com `Access control allow origin`

Comment: com jsop ele faz e recebe a resposta da requisição, só não consegue ler ela, como você pode ver ai na print que eu mandei, ele quebra nos dois pontos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Já que no javascript você espera um JSONP do servidor, então o servidor tem que enviar um JSONP, e não um JSON:

```java
@GET
@Path("email")
@Produces("application/javascript")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getEmail(@QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    ViewStatisticsEmail statisticsEmail = new ViewStatisticsEmail();
    statisticsEmail.setDoacoes(1432);
    statisticsEmail.setLidas(5443);
    statisticsEmail.setNaoLidas(4667);
    statisticsEmail.setSent(10000);
    statisticsEmail.setVisualization("Atualizado por ultimo " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    String json = new Gson().toJson(statisticsEmail);
    return callback + "(" + json + ")";
}
```

Este código é quase igual ao seu código original. As diferenças são:

- `@Produces("application/javascript")` - Afinal de contas, o que ele produz agora é um trecho de javascript, e não um JSON.
- `@QueryParam("callback") String callback` - O parâmetro do `callback` é essencial para que o JSONP funcione.
- `return callback + "(" + json + ")";` - Não basta retornar o JSON, é preciso colocá-lo dentro da chamada ao callback.

Fonte relevante: https://oneminutedistraction.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/using-jsonp-with-jax-rs/

Comment: Vlw cara, estava atrás desta solução desde sabado! foi muito util...